# Pointer gives me the address rather than the value;

Tags: c++, pointers

```
class ZombieLand : public Singleton<ZombieLand>
{
    DECLARE_SINGLETON(ZombieLand);
public:
    MachineState* world[19][19];
    bool map[19][19];

    MachineState* getField(int x, int y)
    {
        return world[x][y];
    }
void setWorld(MachineState state)
{

    world[state.x][state.y] = &state;
    map[state.x][state.y] = true;

}
};

struct MachineState
{
    template <typename MachineTraits>
    friend class Machine;

    enum Facing { UP, RIGHT, DOWN, LEFT};
    MachineState()
        : m_ProgramCounter(1)
        , m_ActionsTaken(0)
        , m_Facing(UP)
        , m_Test(false)
        , m_Memory(nullptr)
        ,x(0)
        ,y(0)
        ,point1(25, 10)
        ,point2(10, 40)
        ,point3(40, 40)
    { }

    int m_ProgramCounter;
    int m_ActionsTaken;
    Facing m_Facing;
    bool m_Test;
    bool m_occupied;
    int x;
    int y;
    Point point1;
    Point point2;
    Point point3;

    int GetActionsPerTurn() const throw() { return m_ActionsPerTurn; }
    int GetMaxMemory() const throw() {return m_MaxMemory; }
    bool GetTruth() const throw() { return m_InfectOnAttack; }
    void setPoint(Point p1, Point p2, Point p3)
    {
        point1=p1;
        point2=p2;
        point3=p3;
    }
};
```

I later call the getField function by doing

```
MachineState *Field1 = ZombieLand::get().getField(state.x, state.y-1 );
```

The problem is that when i try to access a member by doing Field1->getTruth() it's returning me the address of the pointer rather than the actual value(false or true). I don't understand why this is happening

```
template <class T>
class Singleton
{
private:
    static T* _instance;
protected:
    Singleton() {}
public:
    static T& get()
    {
        if (_instance)
        {
            return *_instance;
        }
        else
        {
            _instance = new T();
            return *_instance;
        }
    }
};

if(ZombieLand::get().map[state.x+2][state.y] == true)
{
    MachineState *field3 = ZombieLand::get().getField(state.x+2, state.y);
        std::cout<<"FOUND FIELD"<<Field3->getTruth();
}
```

when this if statement becomes true it prints "FOUND FIELD 0246" onto my console

Comment: There is no `MachineState` code at all. It's weekend, telepathists are resting.

Comment: What does getTruth() returns?

Comment: a boolean true or false

Comment: What does `get()` return?

Comment: ZombieLand implements Singleton design patter. to access anymember variable of zombieland i have to do get() and then the method call. i have added the MachineState code by the way

Comment: Address of *which* pointer? Your question isn't very clear.

Comment: `Field1->getTruth()` cannot return the address of a pointer, it's a bool function. I think you need to explain *why* you think it's returning the address of a pointer. That's probably where your error is.

Comment: i try to output it and it's printing 0246, rather than 0 or 1

Comment: 0246 isn't a pointer value (not unless you have a really unusual computer), show us your output statement.

Comment: `0246` is also not a `bool` value either, which is what `getTruth()` returns. So it is likely a bug in how the value is being logged, rather than begin a bug with the value itself.

Comment: Incidentally the variable you are returning from `GetTruth`, `m_InfectOnAttack`, is not defined anywhere in your code. Where is it defined?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Which is why I want to see the output statement. At the moment we've had loads of code, except the small piece that matters. So far this question seems like a classic example of an XY problem.

Comment: `Field3->getTruth()` is a misprint? Shouldn't it be `field3->getTruth()`? Please cut and paste code, don't try to type it out, too many mistakes that way.

Comment: there is another class that defaults it to false. I have added the statement. This is not just happening with getTruth...if i Try to do Field->X or Field->y it gives me some "random numbers" rather than just a value

Comment: @JohnKemp I think it's becoming abundantly clear the problem is somewhere in the code you haven't posted, or something you're not telling us, or in typos you've made while posting your code. Sorry but I'm giving up. At the moment I'd guess the problem is in 'the other class' which somehow you've failed to mention before now.

Comment: @john thanks, but if you write a small program with the "zombieLand class, and then try to do the MachineStructure * field = ZOmbieLand::get().function you will run into the same problem

Comment: @JohnKemp I don't think so. Good luck in sorting out the problem.

Comment: @JohnKemp I've posted the answer to your problem, you were right in one thing at least, its the ZombieLand class that has the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, now I think you've finally posted the code that has the problem

```
class ZombieLand : public Singleton<ZombieLand>
{
    DECLARE_SINGLETON(ZombieLand);
public:
    MachineState* world[19][19];
    bool map[19][19];

    MachineState* getField(int x, int y)
    {
        return world[x][y];
    }
    void setWorld(MachineState state)
    {
        world[state.x][state.y] = &state;
        map[state.x][state.y] = true;
    }
};
```

This is undefined behaviour because you are saving the pointer to a local variable `state`. The `state` variable gets destroyed after you have exited the `setWorld` function, so your `world` array is just holding pointers to destroyed objects, That's why you have garbage values.

Rewrite this class without pointers.

```
class ZombieLand : public Singleton<ZombieLand>
{
    DECLARE_SINGLETON(ZombieLand);
public:
    MachineState world[19][19];
    bool map[19][19];

    MachineState* getField(int x, int y)
    {
        return &world[x][y];
    }
    void setWorld(const MachineState& state)
    {
        world[state.x][state.y] = state;
        map[state.x][state.y] = true;
    }
};
```

Pointers are almost always a bad idea, you should try to write code without them.

Got there in the end at least.

Answer (score 2):

As we do not have the signature of both `get` and `getField` it is difficult to tell.
But perhaps try

```
*(ZombieLand::get().getField(state.x, state.y-1 ))
```

To get the value that the pointer is pointing to.

**EDIT**

It helps to read the code i.e.

MachineState * world [19][19];

is a 2D array of pointers. Nowhere in this code is those pointers given a value so as it stands you are just lucky that the thing does not just die.

Therefore,

```
   MachineState *getField(int x, int y)
   {
    return world[x][y];
   }
```

As specified by the signature of the function as well!

But where in this code do you give the pointer a value or meaning?

Comment: i have added the singleton...get()...getField() is from ZombieLand...
anytime i try to access a function outside of the class I have to do ZombieLand::get().function()

Comment: i did memset(world,0,sizeof(world)) on the constructor

Comment: that sets it to 0. i didn't add that here because i thought it was irrelevant

Comment: @JohnKemp - Dealing with pointers I would have thought you have a `new` somewhere along the line. BTW starting to use `memset` etc. you are barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: ...I don't follow the barking up the wrong tree. i had to initiate the whole 2D array to null, so memset is the simplest way to do it...y would you use a new?

Comment: For a start I would not use pointers in the first place. As I do not know what you are trying to achieve it is difficult to comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
void setWorld(MachineState state)
{
    world[state.x][state.y] = &state;
    map[state.x][state.y] = true;
}
```

You are initializing the contents of the `world` array with the memory address of a **local variable** on the stack that goes out of scope and is no longer valid after `setWorld()` exits, leaving the array pointing at invalid `MachineState` objects.  When `getField()` is called later on, you get random data from the current call stack.

If you want the array to point to external `MachineState` instances, you need to pass them in by **reference** instead of by **value** so you get the address of the original object and not a temporary anymore:

```
void setWorld(MachineState &state)
{
    world[state.x][state.y] = &state;
    map[state.x][state.y] = true;
}
```

Otherwise, change the array to not hold pointers anymore:

```
class ZombieLand : public Singleton<ZombieLand>
{
    DECLARE_SINGLETON(ZombieLand);
public:
    MachineState world[19][19];
    bool map[19][19];

    MachineState* getField(int x, int y)
    {
        return &world[x][y];
    }

    void setWorld(const MachineState &state)
    {
        world[state.x][state.y] = state;
        map[state.x][state.y] = true;
    }
};
```